# PHP SQLi Newbie Problem. Fetch not returning True

Tags: php, mysqli, return-value, if-statement, fetch

I am a super newbie php person. Just started scripting a week ago. I have this problem with a function not returning true, even though the data seems to be correct. I’ve spent a day+ searching around for answers.

Here is the abbreviated class.

```
public function verifyPost()
{
 try
 {
  if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
    throw new Exception('Invalid Username Password');

  $this->access = 1;
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
  $this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();
 }
}

public function verifySession()
{
 if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
    $this->access = 1;
}

public function verifyDatabase() 
{
 /* connect to db */ 
 $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "user", "password", "world");  

 /* check connection */ 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
        exit(); 
 } 

 /* create prepare statement */ 
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID FROM user WHERE id1 = ? AND id2 = ?"); 
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->id1, $this->id2); 

 /* execute prepared statement */ 
 $stmt->execute(); 

 /* bind variables to prepared statement */ 
 $stmt->bind_result($col1); 

 /* check user info in db and assign returned ID to variable*/ 
 if(($stmt->fetch()) != 0) {
        $this->userid = $col1; 
        return true;
 } else {
        return false;
 }

 /* close statement and connection */ 
 $stmt->close(); 

 /* close connection */ 
 $mysqli->close();
}
```

(I didn't put in the real DB connection info)

For some reason, $access isn’t getting set in  verifySession() bc  verifyDatabase() doesn’t return true. VerifyDatabase() runs through fine. It finds the User/Pass in the Db and doesn’t throw up the exception. The problem occurs at the IF statement. I’ve isolated the it here by commenting out the whole IF statement except for “return true;” and verifySession() sets $access to 1.

Now I thought it might have been fetch(), so I tried an num_rows() instead and still doesn’t return true.

I hope that makes sense. Let me know if i need to elaborate more. Any help is much appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Can you see what exactly it is that fetch returns? Do: $return = $stmt->fetch(); var_dump($return);

Comment: Hi Manos. I put in your line and it returned NULL. Why is that when it executed and bound the results?

Comment: Oh wait. i put that line inside the if statement. If i put it outside, i get bool(true).

Comment: Now even something more curious! If i put the $return here:   /* check user info in db and assign returned ID to variable */ 
  if(($stmt->fetch()) != 0) {
      $this->id = $col1; 

      return true;
  } else {
 $return = $stmt->fetch(); var_dump($return);
      return false;
  }
now the function returns true!

Comment: after some more experimenting, it seems like it is the $stmt->fetch() in the ELSE part that somehow makes it works. i have no idea why, but thanks Manos!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$stmt->fetch can return three values, TRUE, FALSE and NULL.

TRUE  = Success and data was fetched
FALSE = An error occured
NULL  = No more rows/data exists or data truncation occurred

You should be using the triple = operator which enforces type checking aswell, eg.

```
if($stmt->fetch() === true) {
  $this->userid = $col1; 
  return true;
} else
  return false;
```

Or, since this FALSE and NULL will never evaluate to true, you could just write

```
if($stmt->fetch()) {
```

Comment: hey gnif! tried both and they work too! thank you for the help!!